# Spring MVC: formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. I am using aspect-oriented programming (AOP), a programming paradigm that aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns. 
Everything is fine with this class

```
@Aspect
public class MarketingAspect extends ServiceSupport {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.tdk.iot.services.client.LicenseService.*(..))")
    public void handleServiceMethod() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.tdk.iot.services.client.ApplicantService.*(..))")
    public void handleApplicantServiceMethod() {
    }


    @Before("com.tdk.iot.services.aop.ApplicantAspect.handleServiceMethod()")
    public void before(JoinPoint _jp) {
        User user = getLDAPUser();
        if(user != null &&( (user.getUserRole() != UserRole.MARKETING)) {
            throw new NoSufficientRoleException(user == null ? null : user.getUserRole(), UserRole.MARKETING);
        }
    }


    @Before("com.tdk.iot.services.aop.ApplicantAspect.handleApplicantServiceMethod()")
    public void checkRolebefore(JoinPoint _jp) {
        User user = getLDAPUser();
        if(user != null &&( (user.getUserRole() != UserRole.MARKETING))) {
            throw new NoSufficientRoleException(user == null ? null : user.getUserRole(), UserRole.MARKETING);
        }
    }   
}
```

I have changed the method notation  getLDAPUser and now receives HttpServletRequest request as a parameter, so I modified the method as

```
@Before("com.tdk.iot.services.aop.ApplicantAspect.handleApplicantServiceMethod()")
public void checkRolebefore(JoinPoint _jp, HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = getLDAPUser(request);
    if(user != null &&( (user.getUserRole() != UserRole.MARKETING))) {
        throw new NoSufficientRoleException(user == null ? null : user.getUserRole(), UserRole.MARKETING);
    }
}
```

and after modified this method I got this ERROR

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

in my XML:

```
<!-- Scan for aspects -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />       
    <bean id="marketingAspect" class="com.tdk.iot.services.aop.MarketingAspect" />
```

Comment: did you enable spring aop in your config xml file ? the <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> annotations

Comment: can you show your application configurations

Comment: the problem started when I modified the method as follow: public void checkRolebefore(JoinPoint _jp, HttpServletRequest request) {

Comment: can you post the code where you have used this annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the AspectJ basics: The error `formal unbound in pointcut` simply means that your advice declares a parameter not used (bound) by the corresponding pointcut (or vice versa). You can bind parameters to advice method parameters via `args()`, `this()`, `target()`, `@annotation()` etc.

The concrete problem is that in your advice you declare the parameter `HttpServletRequest request`. Where should the value come from? The corresponding pointcut seems to intercept another aspect's advice method which does not have any parameter of type `HttpServletRequest`. So as long as you do not have a source you can tap for the servlet request, you will have to create an instance by yourself.

My impression is you need to learn a bit more about AOP first. Feel free to post more code and explain where you want to get the object from, then I can probably help you fix your code.