# SpringAOP Unbound pointcut parameter error

Tags: spring-aop

The method 'GetRankList' parameter is String, i want to get the parameter by method 'LoginLog'. but the annotation '@Before' has a error,'Unbound pointcut parameter 'str''.
so what should i do? please!
following code:

```java
@PointCut(value="execution(* *.GetRankList(String))")
public void Login(){}

@Before(value="Login()")
public void LoginLog(String str) throws Throwable{
   //todo
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC: formal unbound in pointcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607883/spring-mvc-formal-unbound-in-pointcut)

Comment: yeah,i try to use `&& args`, but its useless . then i find this jar is different, one is spring-aop, other is aspectj.LOL

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions here, providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then click "edit" and update your question. Thank you very much.  P.S.: Your previous comment is quite cryptic. What does your syntax error have to do with the JARs you are talking about? I cannot read your mind, as much as I wish I could. And did you read the other question I linked to, of which this one is a duplicate?